# POST FORM in node and receive data response back to same webpage

Tags: node.js, forms

I have a webpage that takes form details, POSTS the data and should then show the results.  I'm using express for my routing.
This all works fine by resending the data with the HTML template after the POST but I think there must be a better way by hiding the "results" HTML section then just showing it once the data is known from the form.  I've shown a cutdown version of my pages below.
On first load, the page says "your result is undefined", which I would expect but is ugly.
I could remove the "result" section and create a 2nd HTML page to resend from the POST route with it in which would work but I think there must be a better way.
I want to hide the result section on 1st page load then make it appear on the button submit with the result data.  I can get the section hide/unhide but I can't get the data results back to display them.  On button submit the form results just appear in the weburl [www.mywebsite.com/?data](http://www.mywebsite.com/?data) almost like a GET request

I have tried using FormData and npm 'form-data' in a POST  but can't get it working following these examples https://javascript.info/formdata and https://www.npmjs.com/package/form-data.

My structure in Node is
Router.js file

```
    return res.send(htmlFormTemplate({}));

});



router.post('/css', 
        [],
    async (req, res) => {
        
        let {data} = req.body;
    ///
result= do some calculation on {data}   
    ///
        return  res.send(htmlFormTemplate({result}));
});
```

The htmlFormTemplate is a js file

```
module.exports = ({result}) => {
    
   return `  
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <head>
    
  </head>
  
<body>

<form class="box"  method ="POST">  
<inputname="data" />
<button>Submit</button>
</form>

<script>
///tried form processing here
</script>

<section id="Results">
            <ul><li>Your result is ${result}</li></ul>
</section>

</body> 
</html>
 `;
};
```

I'm self-taught and new so hope this makes sense and thanks for any help/ideas

Answer (score 1):

There is a very simple to solve this problem,
just use some templating engine for ex EJS, its very easy to use and will help you better,

and your result is undefined because your using a promise and it might have happened that the response might have not come and you loaded the page. Just use await

```
return await res.send(htmlFormTemplate({result}));
```

Answer (score 0):

You can check if the result variable is null before it gets to the section div:

```
${ result === null ?  '' :
`<section id="Results">
            <ul><li>Your result is ${result}</li></ul>
</section>`}
```

Like this, it wont show the result div if result if null.

Comment: Sorry I haven't made myself clear.  I have a working solution if I do a conventional POST with the form, I get the data in my router.js file and when I do the "res.send(htmlFormTemplate({result}))" it sends the data and displays it no problem.  This works though on the basis of resending the whole page.  I wondered if it can be done better by just hiding the "Results" section and on the Form Button Submit the data gets sent, processed, sent back to the page and then the "Results" section becomes unhidden with the results now showing.  Maybe I'm trying to overcomplicate this.